# Google Cloud alerts to Opsgenie alerting system

Tags: integration, opsgenie, gcp-alerts

for example: i have GCP alert set high cpu usage for vm and this will send email to my team.
Im exploring a way to enable those GCP alerts send to Opsgenie. So then i can configure escalation workflow so Opsgenie can alert relevant team member.
Now i'm stuck since Opsgenie has no direct integration with GCP alerts/alarms.
How i can do this? if API is the only way, can share some light on the integration?

Answer (score 0):

On Opsgenie side: create an integration with "Google Stackdriver": https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/integrate-opsgenie-with-google-stackdriver/

On GCP Cloud Monitoring side: send your alert to the notification channel you have webhooked to Opsgenie:
[enable sending to Opsgenie notification channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgJhZ.png)

Done. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).